# Do I use ViewHolder correctly? Everithing is worked, but i still have doubts with the ListView optimization with holder recycler

Tags: java, android, listview, android-viewholder

I am just adapting my custom adapter code with ViewHolder so that i can optimize my list view with a recycler, but i am not sure if i do it right.

My view holder class:

```
public class ViewHolderTask {
int positionHolder;
TextView nameHolder;
TextView timeHolder;
TextView sessionHolder;
TextView dateHolder;
FloatingActionButton mFabTaskHolder;

public ViewHolderTask(View v, int position) {
    this.positionHolder = position;
    this.nameHolder = v.findViewById(R.id.taskNameText);
    this.timeHolder = v.findViewById(R.id.timeTextView);
    this.sessionHolder = v.findViewById(R.id.textViewSession);
    this.dateHolder = v.findViewById(R.id.dateTextView);
    this.mFabTaskHolder = v.findViewById(R.id.myFabTask);
}
```

My custom adapter class:

```
@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolderTask holder;
    if(convertView == null){

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(
                Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE );
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.task_row, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolderTask(convertView, position);
        convertView.setTag(holder);

    }else{
        holder = (ViewHolderTask) convertView.getTag();
    }
    Task task = taskArrayList.get(position);
    //set the configurations
    holder.getTimeHolder().setText(getTimeString(task.getTime()));
    holder.getNameHolder().setText(task.getName());
    holder.getDateHolder().setText(getDateString(task.getDate()));
    holder.getSessionHolder().setText(getSessionString(task.getSession()));
    //Set the FAB listener
    addFabListener(holder.getmFabTaskHolder(), position);

    //set the clicked background
    if(TaskActivity.getIsClicked() && TaskActivity.getPositionClicked()-1 == position){
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.backgroundSelectedItem);
    }

    return convertView;
}
```

Do I use it right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fine for me other than this portion of the code

```
  //set the clicked background
    if(TaskActivity.getIsClicked() && TaskActivity.getPositionClicked()-1 == position){
        convertView.setBackgroundResource(R.color.backgroundSelectedItem);
    }
```

You might need to reset the background resource back to default for the item which is not clicked. maybe you have to add "else" part to the  "if"

Comment: No, it won't reset background i added some code to prevent it on my other activity, but thank you!